# Esta operação criaria um documento estruturado incorretamente. XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xdocument

Estou a tentar criar um XML, mas não estou a conseguir. Quero que tenha este formato:

```
<item>
      <linktext></linktext>
      <etc..></etc...>
</item>
```

Consigo adicionar **um** item, mas quando vou outra vez pelo loop, ele vai sai do `try` e da-me o erro do título. O que estou a fazer errado? Veja aqui como crio o XML:

```
XDocument xmlOut = new XDocument();
 XElement item = new XElement("item",
                        new XElement("linktext", processedXML),
                        new XElement("link", "http://www.boe.es/diario_boe/txt.php?id=" + tmpName[1]),
                        new XElement("guid", newPdf.ToString()),
                        new XElement("pubDate", DateTime.Now)
                        );

                    xmlOut.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema era que eu estava tentando adicionar vários elementos na raíz do XML, o que é errado (pelo que percebi depois de algumas pesquisas). O que fiz foi criar um `XElement` `<itens>` e depois em vez de:

```
xmlOut.Add(item);
```

usei

```
xmlOut.Root.Element("itens").Add(item);
```

e o problema ficou resolvido, tendo vários `<item>` dentro de `<itens>`, como o pretendido.